# I have a scenario where I need valid conditions existing in my database on the fly

Tags: java, database, postgresql, rule-engine

I have a use case where I have to save conditions in my database, this Is a one time thing. Once this is done we just provide the dto and need to get all the valid conditions.
I have around 20million conditions.
Example of a condition is as follows ->

```
[
  {
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "criteria": "model",
    "value": "1000"
  },
  {
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "operator": "EQUALS",
    "criteria": "ID",
    "value": "test2"
  },
  {
    "dataType": "STRING",
    "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
    "criteria": "DEVICE_MODEL",
    "value": "100"
  }
]
```

As you can see this is 1 condition. Right now I am using jsonb column in Postgres and when I get a request body I have a or condition and I just query for any matching response.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE condition_list @> '[{"value": "test2"}]' OR condition_list @> '[{"value": "1000"}] .....';
```

And In my codebase I am validating rest of the conditions. The response time for me is around 1s. I want much faster response time , to achieve this I will need a database which will give me a better response, by validating the complete conditions.

Rule engines seem to be slow. What should I plan on using?
Or should I just stick with the jsonb column in psql ?

My service is running on spring boot.

Here is the table ddl

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.data
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('data_id_seq'::regclass),
    condition_list jsonb,
    return_value character varying(4000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    service_id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT data PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_dp FOREIGN KEY (name, service_id)
        REFERENCES public.default_properties (name, service_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Index is on jsonb column

```
CREATE INDEX idx_jsonb ON data USING GIN (condition_list jsonb_path_ops);
```

Reason of using a jsonb column is that there criteria are not fixed and sometimes there can be only 1 condition in the list , sometimes more than 5. So there will be so many columns that will be empty.

Comment: If your model is rarely changed - as you stated "one time thing" - then you should keep it in memory for better performance. I can think here about cache systems like Redis, Hazelcast or Aerospike. To name only few examples.

Comment: There are more than 20million conditions/rows, any of them can be true at any point of time. Keeping conditions cashed does not make sense for me. Can u suggest some other database?

Comment: Please update the post with the table's DDL including indexes.

Comment: Please post the actual probelmatic query and the results of running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on that query. Does the reported response time of ~1s apply to just the query, or does it include additional rule engine processing?